# How do I handle objects that are part of a Model object’s state, but don’t need separate db-level support?

Tags: google-app-engine

In my Google App Engine app I have model objects that need to be stored. These objects are parameterized by various policy objects. For example, my Event class has a Privacy policy object which determines who can see, update, etc. There are various subclasses of PrivacyPolicy that behave differently. The Event consults its PrivacyPolicy object at various points.

```
class PrivacyPolicy(db.Model):
    def can_see(self, event, user):
        pass

class OwnerOnlyPolicy(PrivacyPolicy):
    def can_see(self, event, user):
        return user == event.owner

class GroupOnlyPolicy(PrivacyPolicy):
    def can_see(self, event, user):
        for grp in event.owner.groups()
            if grp.is_member(user):
                return True
        return False

class OnlyCertainUsersPolicy(PrivacyPolicy):
    def __init__(self, others):
        self.others = others

    def can_see(self, event, user):
        return user in others
```

I could make my Event class use a ReferenceProperty to the PrivacyPolicy:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    privacy: db.ReferenceProperty(PrivacyPolicy)
    #…
```

The reason I don’t like this is that the one-to-one relationship means that nobody every queries for the policy object, there is no need to maintain the back-reference from the policy to its Event object, and in no other way is PrivacyPolicy an independent db-level object. It is functionally equivalent to an IntegerProperty, in that it is part of the Event object’s state, it’s just an object instead of a number — specifically it’s an object that can have zero state or lots of state, unknown to the Event type.

I can’t find anyone talking about how to approach such a situation. Is there a tool/approach I don’t know about? Do I just suck it up and use a reference property and the hell with the overhead?

If the only other way to handle this is a custom Property type, any advice about how to approach it would be welcome. My first thought is to use a TextProperty to store the string rep of the policy object (`policy`), decode it when needed, caching the result, and having any change to the policy object invalidate the cache and update the string rep.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating by trying to store this in the datastore.  This belongs in code rather than in the datastore.

The least complicated way would be:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    privacy = db.IntegerProperty()

    def can_see(self, user):
        if self.privacy == PRIVACY_OWNER_ONLY:
            return user == event.owner
        else if self.privacy == PRIVACY_GROUP:
            for grp in self.owner.groups()
                if grp.is_member(user):
                    return True
            return False
```

Comment: Well, some of the decisions are complicated, and I want to be able to extend the types of policies later, without rewriting the Event class. This is pretty typical OO design, is it just not a supported approach in GAE?

Comment: You're running around in circles.  It is supported in GAE, the way you did it in your question, it just isn't a good idea.  Typical OO design combines data and behaviour inside an object.  But the datastore is designed to store data.  You want to separate your datastore object (in this case the IntegerProperty) from your PrivacyPolicy object.  You can create a separate PrivacyPolicy object that you instantiate on __init__ based on the value of the "privacy" IntegerProperty.  That would be the OO way to do it.  You'll manage the same code, in various class methods instead of one "if" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes all it takes is to think of the right approach. The solution is to introduce a new kind of property that uses pickle to store and retrieve values, such as that described in https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/bwMD0ZfRnJg

I wanted something slightly more sophisticated, because pickle isn’t always the answer, and anyway documentation is nice, so here is my ObjectReference type:

```
import pickle
from google.appengine.ext import db

class ObjectProperty(db.Property):
    def __init__(self, object_type=None, verbose_name=None, to_store=pickle.dumps, from_store=pickle.loads, **kwds):
        """Initializes this Property with all the given options

        All args are passed to the superclass. The ones used specifically by this class are described here. For
        all other args, see base class method documentation for details.

        Args:
          object_type: If not None, all values assigned to the property must be either instances of this type or None
          to_store: A function to use to convert a property value to a storable str representation. The default is
            to use pickle.dumps()
          from_store: A function to use to convert a storable str representation to a property value. The default is
            to use pickle.loads()
        """
        if object_type and not isinstance(object_type, type):
            raise TypeError('object_type should be a type object')

        kwds['indexed'] = False         # It never makes sense to index pickled data
        super(ObjectProperty, self).__init__(verbose_name, **kwds)

        self.to_store = to_store
        self.from_store = from_store
        self.object_type = object_type

    def get_value_for_datastore(self, model_instance):
        """Get value from property to send to datastore.

        We retrieve the value of the attribute and return the result of invoking the to_store function on it

        See base class method documentation for details.
        """
        value = getattr(model_instance, self.name, None)
        return self.to_store(value)

    def make_value_from_datastore(self, rep):
        """Get value from datastore to assign to the property.

        We take the value passed, convert it to str() and return the result of invoking the from_store function
        on it. The Property class assigns this returned value to the property.

        See base class method documentation for details.
        """
        # It passes us a unicode, even though I returned a str, so this is required
        rep = str(rep)
        return self.from_store(rep)

    def validate(self, value):
        """Validate reference.

        Returns:
          A valid value.

        Raises:
          BadValueError for the following reasons:
            - Object not of correct type.
        """
        value = super(ObjectProperty, self).validate(value)

        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, self.object_type):
            raise db.KindError('Property %s must be of type %s' % (self.name, self.object_type))

        return value
```